# NSTableCellView Binding Xamarin.Mac

Tags: cocoa, xamarin, cocoa-bindings, monomac, xamarin.mac

Can anyone please help me with NSTableCellView integration and customisation in Xamarin.Mac for Mac App development? Here is Example of Different types of Cells

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqFBs.png

I know I should adopt View Based NSTableView. But I have no idea how to bind datas corresponding to each cell. Please help

Comment: You can bind to keypaths in a custom object through the cell view's `objectValue` keypath.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I need to bind values programatically though.